# No Files Data Django

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django

Форма HTML:

```
<form class="callback_form login-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'dialog' order_id=order.id %}">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group newMess">
        <label class="no-orders" for="text">Новое сообщение</label>
        <textarea placeholder="Текст сообщения" class="form-control unkrestik" type="text" name="text" id="text" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file">К одному сообщению вы можете прикрепить максимум 1 файл!</label>
        <input type="file" name="myfile">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="buttons marg-btn">
</form>
```

Views.py:

```
def dialog(request, order_id=0):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.FILES['myfile']:
            myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        else:
            myfile = None
        postBody = request.POST.get('text', '')
        new_message = Message(body=postBody, order=order_newmess, writer=user, file=myfile)
        new_message.save()
        return render(request, 'orders/dialog.html')
```

Model с FileField:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete='CASCADE')
    writer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete='CASCADE')
    body = models.TextField()
    postDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=generateURL, blank=True, null=True)
```

generateURL смысла давать нет, ошибка в том, что когда я пытаюсь взять данные с помощью `request.FILES['myfile']`, появляется ошибка от Django, мол myfile не найден. Также в ошибке указаны все данные из request. Так вот в данных request файл находится в POST запросе и то содержит только название файла. А ведь сам файл ещё не обработан! Помогите пожалуйста, не пойму, в чём дело.

P.S. читал про UploadFileForm, но начал так делать и тем более нужно будет совмещать поле для файла с полем для текста (textarea в форме)

Comment: `if 'myfile' in request.FILES:`

Comment: спасибо огромное, помогло!!!

Answer (score 0):

Вроде все правильно, проверьте точно ли файл посылается, например возьмите самый простой файл маленького размера названный английскими именами. 
Если вы файл посылаете файл через ngin, то там стоит ограницение на размер